# Calling CTE multiple times in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly complicated query with multiple CTEs but 1 main CTE that the others all pull from, does this cause that main CTE to be executed multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CROSS JOIN thus:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN instructorID = @instructorID THEN score END) InstructorSemesterAverage,
    STDEVP(CASE WHEN instructorID = @instructorID THEN score END) InstructorSemesterSTDeviation,
    AVG(CASE WHEN subjectCode = @subjectCode THEN score END) DepartmentSemesterAverage, 
    STDEVP(CASE WHEN subjectCode = @subjectCode THEN score END) DepartmentSemesterSTDeviation, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN bannerCRN=@CRN AND Q.year = @year AND semester = @semester THEN score END) ClassScore,
    STDEVP(CASE WHEN bannerCRN=@CRN AND Q.year = @year AND semester = @semester THEN score END) ClassSTDeviation,
    (SELECT DecTile FROM cteNtile WHERE instructorID = @instructorID)*10 DecTile,
    X.DepartmentClassFiveYearAverage AS DepartmentClassFiveYearAverage,
    X.DepartmentClassFiveYearSTDeviation AS DepartmentClassFiveYearSTDeviation,
    X.InstructorClassFiveYearAverage AS InstructorClassFiveYearAverage,
    X.InstructorClassFiveYearSTDeviation AS InstructorClassFiveYearSTDeviation
FROM 
    cteMain Q CROSS JOIN cteFiveYear X
```

This will prevent multiple executions (for actual execution plan see `Number of Executions` property) for `cteFiveYear`.

Example: If you execute this query

```
SELECT  h.ProductID,h.StandardCost,
        x.AvgPrice
FROM    Production.ProductCostHistory h
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  AVG(p.ListPrice) AvgPrice
    FROM    Production.Product p
) x
```

using `AdventureWorks2008R2` database then the actual execution plan will be
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(50),
        TypeID INT
)

DECLARE @TableTypes TABLE(
        TypeID INT,
        TypeName VARCHAR(50)
)

;WITh Vals AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROm    @Table
        WHERE   ID > 10
)
, UsingVals1 AS (
        SELECT  v.*,
                tt.TypeName
        FROm    Vals v INNER JOIN
                @TableTypes tt ON v.TypeID = tt.TypeID
)
, UsingVals2 AS (
        SELECT  v.*,
                tt.TypeName
        FROm    Vals v INNER JOIN
                @TableTypes tt ON v.TypeID = tt.TypeID
        WHERE   tt.TypeName LIKE '%%'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    UsingVals1
UNION 
SELECT  *
FROM    UsingVals2
```

And then at this [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18419)

You will notice from the execution plan that the Vals CTE section is executed twice.

Maybe also have a look at [How many times the T-SQL inside the CTE is executed?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/juggling_with_sql/2011/12/15/how-many-times-the-t-sql-inside-the-cte-is-executed/)

Comment: Thanks I googled for a bit but couldn't find anything conclusive, I guess I'll have to use temp tables for this since it's slow as molasses.

Comment: @Preston, before you start using temp tables, I'd recommend looking at execution plan for your query and determining if an index strategy will improve query performance

Comment: @zfus Unfortunately it's not my database, it's actually the main testing database at my university and while they don't mind putting my query in a stored proc they won't make other changes for me.