# Why CTE calculation is duplicated in query plan and how to optimize it without duplicating code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, common-table-expression, sql-execution-plan

Calculation of grp_set is duplicated 4 times in query plan of this query (distinct sort takes 23% each time, so it takes 23 * 4 = 92% of all resources):

```
with
     grp_set as (select distinct old_num,old_tbl,old_db,old_val_num from err_calc)
    ,grp as (select id = row_number() over (order by old_num),* from grp_set)

    ,leaf as (select grp.id ,c.* ,sort = convert(varchar(max),old_col) + " - " + severity + " - " + err
        from grp
        join err_calc c on
                            c.old_num   = grp.old_num
                        and c.old_tbl       = grp.old_tbl
                        and c.old_db        = grp.old_db
                        and c.old_val_num   = grp.old_val_num
    )

    select old_num,old_tbl,old_db,old_val_num,conc.*
        from (select sep=",") sep
        cross join grp
        cross apply (select
             old_col    = stuff((select sep + old_col   from leaf where leaf.id = grp.id order by leaf.sort FOR XML PATH("")),1,len(sep),"")
            ,old_val    = stuff((select sep + old_val   from leaf where leaf.id = grp.id order by leaf.sort FOR XML PATH("")),1,len(sep),"")
            ,severity   = stuff((select sep + severity  from leaf where leaf.id = grp.id order by leaf.sort FOR XML PATH("")),1,len(sep),"")
            ,err        = stuff((select sep + err       from leaf where leaf.id = grp.id order by leaf.sort FOR XML PATH("")),1,len(sep),"")
        ) conc
```

Table err_calc contains about 350K records and it has only one index by old_db,old_tbl,new_tbl,severity,err,old_col,new_col,old_val_num,old_val,old_num,new_num.

The purpose of this query is to concatenate 4 string fields per group due to lack of concatenation aggregate in SQL.

Equivalent and desired query if concatenation aggregate existed or was implemented with CLR and if order by could be applied to source of aggregation and if all grouping fields could be referenced by `grouping.*` would be:

```
select grouping.*
    ,severity   =conc(sep+severity)
    ,err        =conc(sep+err)
    ,old_col    =conc(sep+old_col)
    ,old_val    =conc(sep+old_val)
    from err_calc
    cross join (select sep=',') sep
    group by old_num,old_tbl,old_db,old_val_num
    order by old_col,severity,err
```

Comment: I know that duplication can be avoided by using temp table, but why do I have to use temp table in this case ?

Comment: Related; [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/)

Comment: @Martin Smith: Putting select distinct top (2147483647) old_num,old_tbl,old_db,old_val_num from err_calc order by old_num,old_tbl,old_db,old_val_num did not help, so as top 100 percent.

Comment: Even if it did it would be quite a hacky way. If you want it materialized you're best off doing it yourself into a temporary table containing all required columns from `leaf` and indexed on `id,sort`

Comment: This query is part of a view ?

Comment: @Boghdan: Yes, I define view with this query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is used like a subquery, and used multiple times. cf. [Calling CTE multiple times in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094760/calling-cte-multiple-times-in-same-query)

You should rewrite your query with a `JOIN` with your CTE instead of a `CROSS APPLY`, and put the logic of string concatenation in the `SELECT` part of your query, then the CTE will be called once.

Comment: Why SQL does not optimize identical subqueries ?

Comment: @alpav: It does optimize it. If it was cheaper to materialize the cte in your case, Postgres would do so and you'd see a materialize step in the query plan.

Comment: Moving cross apply calculations into select did not help. Could you paste some example of rewriting ? The reason I wrote this way is to avoid code duplication, so I would prefer sample that does not have much code duplication. My problem is: I cannot use one FOR XML to generate 4 lists.

Comment: hard to do without test data. Would you mind posting some data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @rudi: I have about 350K records in err_calc table and you can put any strings&numbers into these fields. It has only one index by old_db,old_tbl,new_tbl,severity,err,old_col,new_col,old_val_num,old_val,old_num,new_num.