# In which situations intermediate materialization trick works or does not work?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, subquery

In question [Why CTE calculation is duplicated in query plan and how to optimize it without duplicating code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20789982/195446) one of comments suggested that it's possible to materialize subquery using trick described [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/).

The trick is to put `top` and `order by` into subquery.

When I tried it, it didn't work in my situation (described in my question).

In which situations does this trick work and in which situations it does not work ?

Can I use `top 100 percent` instead of `top (2147483647)` ?

Do I have to specify `order by` ?

Does it depend on presence of indexes, statistics or where clause ?

Does it work for subquery from another database or linked servers ?

Does it work in ... e.t.c. ?

Comment: The top-trick does not prevent duplicated execution of the CTE. It changes the plan shape in other ways, but this has nothing to do with CTEs.

Comment: Right, it does not remove all steps of duplicated part of the plan, but it is supposed to remove some expensive steps.

Comment: What this trick does is convert the nested result set into an independent, sorted stream of rows (the output of a sort operator). This tends to result in merge or hash joins. It tends to suppress loop joins with the nested query as the inner side. The linked connect bug is meaningless to me because I do not have the query plans. Probably, this CTE trick improved performance by accident. Honestly, I think this question is not answerable without a concrete example. Provide a SqlFiddle and I'll answer if I can.